# How can one determine when items are distinguishable when counting a number of ways?

Tags: probability

I have been working on the Harvard Stats 110 curriculum for my own enrichment, and I have run into the same misunderstanding twice.

Consider the following question:

A college has ten (non-overlapping) time slots for its courses, and assigns
courses to time slots randomly and independently. A student randomly chooses three of
the courses to enroll in. What is the probability
that there is a conflict in the student’s schedule?

As part of the solution, it is stated that there are $10^3$ possible schedules. My question is: doesn't this assume that the courses are distinguishable when they should not be? It should be irrelevant if course A or course B is at 9 am, as long as it is known that there is some course at 9 am.

For those familiar with this course, a following question states that there are $6^6$ ways for six robberies to occur in six districts, but I believe that this again assumes that robberies are distinct when I don't believe that they should be.

I certainly see why we should calculate the number of ways with replacement, but why does order matter in these instances? Shouldn't order of classes or robberies be irrelevant, because they are indistinguishable.

Thank you in advance for your help and insight!

Comment: What is the driving focus on whether to treat them as distinguishable/indistinguishable in the *approach* to the problem is not whether or not they are distinguishable/indistinguishable in the actual scenario but rather *the random process used when determining what the final outcome is when performing the experiment*.  In many of these, the only sensible way of implementing the random selections is one at a time and in such a scenario we can at the time of selection distinguish between them based on what time it was we selected them, even if we subsequently forget this information.

Comment: Compare this to the problem of taking two indistinguishable *to the casual observer* coins, putting them in a cup, shaking it around, and pouring the coins out and noting the number of heads.  Compare that to the problem of taking two similar coins but who have different identifying marks (*e.g. year of printing*) and doing the same.  Compare this to the problem of having those similar coins but being tossed by a casual observer who didn't bother looking at the years.  Finally, compare this to if we didn't use the cup but instead tossed them one after another.  They all have same distribution.

Comment: Roll a ten-sided die three times. What's the probability that some value occurs more than once? Or roll three ten-sided dice and ask the same question. Same problem in both cases, regardless of whether the dice are all the same color. Treat them as distinguishable since it gives you equally likely outcomes.